# How to reset the cockpit view in flightgear?

Tags: flightgear

In the initial cockpit few not all instruments and handles can be seen, so I managed to be able to change the view angle to be able to see controls covered by other controls, but now, I can't see outside the aircraft. How to reset the view to the initial position/angle?

Wiki articles, like [Configure views in FlightGear](http://wiki.flightgear.org/Howto:Configure_views_in_FlightGear) contain XML markup, so must refer to hacking flightgear instead of using it (and, of course, fail to mention that at the beginning together with a link to a usage article).

Other findable articles cover experimental camera add-ons, like http://wiki.flightgear.org/FGCamera.